# How to represent a set of flags in SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, language-agnostic

I have a data class:

```
class Dialog {
public:
    string name;
    std::vector<Permission> permissions;
}

enum class Permission {
   CAN_EDIT = 1,
   CAN_DELETE,
   CAN_RENAME
};
```

Which I need to save in SQLite database. How can I represent a set of permissions in database?

Comment: I would make this a bitmask, get rid of the vector and straight out write the numerical value in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see essentially three ways:

- you can go fully explicit, relational and normalized: have a table with the available permissions, and a bridge table with the dialog ID and the associated permissions (classic many to many mapping); this may make sense for extremely dynamic systems, with new permissions kinds being added dynamically and the like; IMO generally more hassle than it's worth, and quite inefficient;
- if the type of permissions isn't going to change much over time (and is going to stay low), you can embed the permissions in the dialog table schema, so you'll have a `can_edit`, `can_rename`, `can_delete` boolean columns; this is quite explicit as well, but requires a change of schema every time you add a permission type; also "pollutes" the dialog table schema with all the permission types, which can be a burden if they start to be too many;
- you can go "Unix permissions style": make your permissions a bit field (`CAN_EDIT = 1, CAN_DELETE = 2, CAN_RENAME = 4`), get rid of the vector, store the OR-ed value in an `unsigned` field, which will then be mirrored in the DB in a single `permissions` column; I like this one best, as it just requires a single column, doesn't require deduplication of permissions (it is already implicit in the OR), and scales up without problems up to 63 permission types without having to touch the schema.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. Chose second option for it explicitness.